# how to convert text file to Excel file , Without deleting the spaces between data

Tags: python, excel, text

I want to convert text file to excel file, without deleting spaces for each line.

Note that the number of columns will be equal to all lines of the file.

the text file follows the following format:

First row

```
05100079 0000001502 5 01   2 070 1924    02 06 1994 C508 2 8500 3 8500 3 3 1 1 012 10    0 98 00                       4 8 8 9                                                                                               0    40       01              2 15      26000 1748 C508       116 102 3  09 98 013 1 1 0 1 10 10       0 09003     50060 50060 0 0  369 99 9       1 4 4 5 8                          0 0181                        1 80 00 01 0            9 9       8        1 0 00 00 020 0
```

second row

```
05100095 0000001502 2 01   2 059 1917    02 03 1977 C504 2 8500 3 8500 3 9 1 1                   54-11-0999-00         2     9                                                                                               0    90       01              2 12      26000 1744 C504       116 102 3  09 98 013 1 1 0 2             0 09011     50060 50060 0    36   9 9       1 9 9 5 8                          0 3161                                                9 9       8                  020 0             `
```

How to edit the code to convert text file to excel file without deleting the spaces between data?

This code below deletes the space in each line.

## I mean to convert the file to Excel Sheet without any modification to the original file.

The spaces stay spaces and all other data stays the same format.

```
import xlwt
import xlrd

book = xlwt.Workbook()
ws = book.add_sheet('First Sheet')  # Add a sheet

f = open('testval.txt', 'r+')

data = f.readlines() # read all lines at once
for i in range(len(data)):

    row = data[i].split()  # This will return a line of string data, you may need to convert to other formats depending on your use case`

    for j in range(len(row)):
        ws.write(i, j, row[j])  # Write to cell i, j

book.save('testval' + '.xls')
f.close()
```

Expected output: 
Excel file in the same format as the original file"text"

Comment: What do you want to do with the spaces?  If line 0 is `'hello world'` what should the cells look like?

Comment: Do you want an Excel file with only one column containing each line of the text file?

Comment: @james, The data is numbers and texts, and space represents a certain value that there is no "disease" or "patient record" or that there are unregistered data, space can be valuable and can be a data separator.

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE, No, I separated all the fields from each other by blanking the values in the original file, but there are values that are already empty,
What I want to do is separate the data by columns based on the spaces that exist

Comment: So, you want one character in each cell? What is your delimiter? can you edit an give an example?

Comment: Do you mean that each field has a fixed size?

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE, Yes, I mean it, each field has a fixed size, and based on this I added a space after each field to distinguish between the fields,  how to apply this code when converting an Excel file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have fixed-length fields, you need to split each line using index intervals.

For instance, you can do:

```py
book = xlwt.Workbook()
ws = book.add_sheet('First Sheet')  # Add a sheet

with io.open("testval.txt", mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    for row_idx, row in enumerate(f):
        row = row.rstrip()
        ws.write(row_idx, 0, row[0:8])
        ws.write(row_idx, 1, row[9:19])
        ws.write(row_idx, 2, row[20:21])
        ws.write(row_idx, 3, row[22:24])
        # and so on...

book.save("sample.xlsx")
```

You get something like that:

[image]

Comment: LPORTE, I am very grateful to you, thank you for your cooperation